# jQuery Date Picker popup displays below another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

**DatePicker working fine**

[image]

**DatePicker covered but search box with auto-complete**

[image]

I can't seem to figure out why my JQuery Datepicker displays perfectly in all instances except for the second picture. Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: It's a z-index issue. Try modifying the z-index of the Datepicker module.

Comment: `New  Supervisor` has probably `position:relative` with `z-index`. If you will share with us your code, or provide a snippet or public URL we could tell you for sure..

Comment: changed the z-index from 2 to 0 and now it works. Thanks @BenM!

Comment: You need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. Pictures are nice, but we need to see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your css add or change z-index  value for the *select changes* div to a larger value e.g.

```
  z-index:20000;
```

This is to bring the div/box and its content in front